# Using Ransack alias inside another alias

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, alias, ransack

Let us say we defined following ransack aliases:

```
  ransack_alias :city, :adresses_city
  ransack_alias :street, :adresses_street
  ransack_alias :postcode, :adresses_postcode
```

Is there a way to use these aliases in a further ransack alias, like that?

```
  ransack_alias :quick_search, :city_or_street_or_postcode
```

instead of

```
  ransack_alias :quick_search, :adresses_city_or_adresses_postcode_or_adresses_street
```

Are tried it, but it does not work just like that, I wonder if it one can make it work with some further setting.